# How to group values in the table and geting the difference between 2 different columns from 2 different tables

Tags: ms-access

I am having two tables extra and save of all table they have a column sales

```
    Table  extra                           Table  save      
   ITEMS  SALES                           ITEMS  SALES           
     A     15                                A     7                     
     B     20                                B     2                           
     A     2                                 A     5 
     B     2                                 B     2
```

I want to first group elements by items and then subtract a column of sales from table extra from the column of sales in table save and result put in another table of order with columns (items difference)
and result should look like this

```
   Table  order                                
   ITEMS  difference                                    
     A     5                                                  
     B     18
```

Comment: And no database tags? Seriously?

Comment: am working with access database

Comment: Can you show the required result?

Comment: ok result of getting ordertable

Comment: Why does this question have C# tag?

Comment: In case of A: (15+2)-(7+5)=5. Is that what you need?

Comment: sam working on a c # project yah thats wat i need to be able to put the difference of 2 columns of sales from different table in table order

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT T1.ITEMS,T1.extraSales-T2.saveSales as Difference FROM 
(SELECT ITEMS,SUM(SALES) as extraSales FROM extra GROUP BY ITEMS) T1
INNER JOIN 
(SELECT ITEMS,SUM(SALES) as saveSales FROM save GROUP BY ITEMS) T2
ON T1.ITEMS=T2.ITEMS
```

Result:

```
ITEMS   DIFFERENCE
A       5
B       18
```

**EDIT:**

For inserting it to another table:

```
INSERT INTO orderTable VALUES
(
SELECT T1.ITEMS,T1.extraSales-T2.saveSales as Difference FROM 
(SELECT ITEMS,SUM(SALES) as extraSales FROM extra GROUP BY ITEMS) T1
INNER JOIN 
(SELECT ITEMS,SUM(SALES) as saveSales FROM save GROUP BY ITEMS) T2
ON T1.ITEMS=T2.ITEMS
)
```

Comment: so how am i going to insert  the result in table order below because the querry runs without out errors

Comment: @kintumickeal: Did my query get you what you are looking for? If yes, feel free to accept the answer so that it could help others in future to find the right answer.